# can't upgrade a package... it wants to delete everything

Tags: apt, 21.04

I get "The following packages have been kept back"

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libgbm1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386
  libosmesa6:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

So I tried to install them individually, and get following response:

```
sudo apt install libgbm1:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  astrometry.net brainparty-data folks-common font-manager-common font-viewer
  fonts-cantarell fonts-font-awesome fonts-lato fonts-league-spartan
  fonts-noto-extra fonts-noto-ui-extra fonts-open-sans gir1.2-camel-1.2
  gir1.2-ebookcontacts-1.2 gir1.2-edataserver-1.2 gir1.2-evince-3.0
  gir1.2-folks-0.6 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gfbgraph-0.2 gir1.2-granite-1.0
  gir1.2-gsound-1.0 gir1.2-handy-0.0 gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 gir1.2-rest-0.7
  gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 gir1.2-xapp-1.0 gist
  gstreamer1.0-adapter-pulseeffects gstreamer1.0-autogain-pulseeffects
  gstreamer1.0-convolver-pulseeffects gstreamer1.0-crystalizer-pulseeffects
  hijra-applet indi-bin kpackagetool5 kwayland-data libadplug-2.3.3-0
  libappimage0 libasound2-dev libastrometry0 libatk-bridge2.0-dev
  libatspi2.0-dev libaudiofile1 libavresample4 libbinio1v5 libcddb2
  libcfitsio-bin libcfitsio9 libdbus-1-dev libebur128-1 libenca0 liberfa1
  libfam0 libfdk-aac2 libfolks25 libgfbgraph-0.2-0 libgl-dev libgles1
  libglew2.1 libglu1-mesa-dev libglx-dev libgranite-common libgranite5
  libgsl25 libgslcblas0 libhfstospell11 libibus-1.0-dev libindi-data
  libindi-plugins libindialignmentdriver1 libindidriver1 libiso9660-11
  libixml10 libjpeg62 libjs-jquery-datatables libjs-jquery-hotkeys
  libjs-jquery-isonscreen libjs-jquery-metadata libjs-jquery-tablesorter
  libjs-jquery-throttle-debounce libkf5archive5 libkf5attica5 libkf5auth-data
  libkf5codecs-data libkf5codecs5 libkf5completion-data libkf5config-bin
  libkf5config-data libkf5configcore5 libkf5configwidgets-data
  libkf5coreaddons-data libkf5coreaddons5 libkf5dbusaddons-bin
  libkf5dbusaddons-data libkf5declarative-data libkf5dnssd-data libkf5dnssd5
  libkf5doctools5 libkf5globalaccel-data libkf5i18n-data libkf5i18n5
  libkf5iconthemes-data libkf5itemviews-data libkf5jobwidgets-data
  libkf5kdegames-data libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5newstuff-data
  libkf5notifications-data libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5package-data
  libkf5package5 libkf5service-data libkf5solid5-data libkf5sonnet5-data
  libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5wallet-data
  libkf5widgetsaddons-data libkf5windowsystem-data libkf5xmlgui-bin
  libkf5xmlgui-data liblua5.2-0 libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common libmad0
  libmcpp0 libmd4c0 libminizip1 libmpdclient2 libmusicbrainz5-2
  libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libnova-0.16-0 libopengl-dev libopengl0 libopusfile0
  liborc-0.4-dev liborc-0.4-dev-bin libphysfs1 libpulse-dev libqrcodegencpp1
  libqscintilla2-qt5-l10n libqt5concurrent5 libqt5dbus5 libqt5keychain1
  libqt5network5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5qml5 libqt5qmlmodels5
  libqt5qmlworkerscript5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite
  libqt5texttospeech5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webengine-data libqt5websockets5
  libqt5xml5 libraqm0 libre2-9 librlottie0-1 libruby2.7 libsdl-image1.2
  libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libsidplayfp5 libsndio-dev libsquashfuse0 libsquish0
  libudev-dev libupnp13 libva-wayland2 libvoikko1 libvorbisidec1
  libwayland-bin libwayland-dev libwcs7 libx11-xcb-dev libxapp1 libxcb-record0
  libxcb-screensaver0 libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0 libxkbcommon-dev
  libxss-dev libxt-dev libxtst-dev libxv-dev libxxf86vm-dev libzita-convolver4
  libzzip-0-13 lsp-plugins-jack lsp-plugins-lv2 python3-astrometry
  python3-astropy python3-cov-core python3-coverage python3-erfa python3-exif
  python3-exifread python3-hijra python3-hypothesis python3-imdbpy
  python3-nose2 python3-pytest-arraydiff python3-pytest-astropy
  python3-pytest-astropy-header python3-pytest-cov python3-pytest-doctestplus
  python3-pytest-filter-subpackage python3-pytest-openfiles
  python3-pytest-remotedata python3-sortedcontainers python3-xlib
  qml-module-qtqml qml-module-qtqml-models2 qt5-style-kvantum-l10n
  qtspeech5-speechd-plugin rake realmd rubberband-ladspa ruby ruby-minitest
  ruby-net-telnet ruby-power-assert ruby-rubygems ruby-test-unit ruby-xmlrpc
  ruby2.7 rubygems-integration scrcpy-server simplescreenrecorder-lib
  sonnet-plugins source-extractor supertux-data supertuxkart-data
  wayland-protocols x11proto-record-dev x11proto-scrnsaver-dev
  x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev xapps-common xplanet xplanet-images xsltproc
  zam-plugins
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  appimagelauncher apturl atril blueman brainparty cantata cheese
  chrome-gnome-shell code evolution-data-server ffmpeg flameshot focuswriter
  font-manager freeglut3-dev gdm3 ghostwriter gimp gir1.2-champlain-0.12
  gir1.2-cheese-3.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0
  gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0
  gir1.2-gtkchamplain-0.12 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-7 gir1.2-rb-3.0
  gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-calendar gnome-control-center
  gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-initial-setup gnome-maps
  gnome-online-accounts gnome-remote-desktop gnome-session-bin gnome-shell
  gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-caffeine
  gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect
  gnome-shell-extension-hijra gnome-shell-extension-panel-osd
  gnome-shell-extension-prefs gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
  gnome-shell-extension-weather gnome-shell-extensions
  gnome-startup-applications gnome-sushi gnome-todo gnome-tweak-tool
  gnome-tweaks gnome-user-docs gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-gl
  gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-vaapi hypnotix
  kapman kazam kded5 kio kpackagelauncherqml kstars kstars-data
  kwayland-integration libatrilview3 libavdevice58 libchamplain-0.12-0
  libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libclutter-1.0-0
  libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20
  libcogl20 libdbusmenu-qt5-2 libedataserverui-1.2-3 libegl-dev libegl-mesa0
  libegl1 libegl1-mesa-dev libepoxy-dev libfluidsynth2 libfolks-eds25 libgbm1
  libgegl-0.4-0 libgimp2.0 libgl1-mesa-dev libgles-dev libglvnd-dev
  libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgranite-dev libgstreamer-gl1.0-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libkf5authcore5
  libkf5completion5 libkf5configgui5 libkf5configwidgets5 libkf5crash5
  libkf5dbusaddons5 libkf5declarative5 libkf5globalaccel-bin
  libkf5globalaccel5 libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5guiaddons5
  libkf5iconthemes-bin libkf5iconthemes5 libkf5idletime5 libkf5itemviews5
  libkf5jobwidgets5 libkf5kdegames7 libkf5kdegamesprivate1 libkf5kiocore5
  libkf5kiogui5 libkf5kiowidgets5 libkf5kirigami2-5 libkf5newstuff5
  libkf5newstuffcore5 libkf5notifications5 libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5plotting5
  libkf5quickaddons5 libkf5service-bin libkf5service5 libkf5solid5
  libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5wallet-bin libkf5wallet5
  libkf5waylandclient5 libkf5widgetsaddons5 libkf5windowsystem5 libkf5xmlgui5
  libkwalletbackend5-5 libmikmod3 libmpv1 libmutter-7-0 libpolkit-qt5-1-1
  libqscintilla2-qt5-15 libqt5charts5 libqt5gui5 libqt5multimedia5
  libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5quick5 libqt5quickcontrols2-5
  libqt5quicktemplates2-5 libqt5quickwidgets5 libqt5svg5 libqt5waylandclient5
  libqt5waylandcompositor5 libqt5webenginecore5 libqt5webenginewidgets5
  libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5x11extras5 libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl2-2.0-0
  libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-2.0-0 libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0
  libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-dev libtotem0
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libyelp0 mpd mplayer mugshot mutter nautilus-share
  obs-studio peek pulseeffects python3-kivy python3-pygame
  qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2 qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons
  qml-module-org-kde-newstuff qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects
  qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-controls2
  qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-templates2
  qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2 qt5-gtk-platformtheme
  qt5-image-formats-plugins qt5-style-kvantum qtwayland5 scrcpy shotwell
  simplescreenrecorder sqlitebrowser stacer supertux supertuxkart
  telegram-desktop totem totem-plugins typecatcher ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-docs ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
  ubuntu-session update-manager update-notifier virtualbox-qt vym
  webtorrent-desktop xorg xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core
  xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-libinput
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
  xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
  xwayland yelp zeal zenity
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgbm1:i386
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 242 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 30.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,596 MB disk space will be freed.
```

Ubuntu 21.04
Gnome 3.38.5

Can someone help me out???

==========================

A few hours later I did update and upgrade and new files were downloaded and all issues disappeared...
Do not know what happened but PROBLEM SOLVED

Thanks for all the replies :)

Comment: @ZeissIkon Actually, that's not entirely true - some things like drivers have 32bit components that are required, and they're 'whitelisted' for 32bit library inclusion.  In this case, OP's probably trying to upgrade a 32bit library which affects the core GUI components of the 64bit libraries, and in turn is staring at the abyss.  I agree, we need more info on the version of Ubuntu they're using and where they're getting that package from that's i386 which is breaking everything

Comment: ubuntu 21.04 ... isn't this strange???

Comment: Tagged version.  It might also help to tag the flavor you're using (Budgie, MATE, Kubuntu, etc.) as well as what video, and [edit] in some system specs.

Comment: What do you mean with video???  Graphic Card???  if yes ... then AMD

Comment: try doing a `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: Yes... the first thing I tried was dist-upgrade... but didn't work

Comment: Make sure the kept packages are the same versions like the 64bit on your system